# Password Proctected the DeviceLibrary.zip folder

Tags: c#-4.0

Only its creating the password protected for child file .
But I need the full folder as a Password Protected`

```
string folderToZip = @"C:\HCF";
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string zipFileName = "DeviceLibrary.zip";
string ddlFolderName = "DeviceLibrary";
string extractionPath = @"C:\DeviceLibrary\";

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = guid.ToString();
    zip.AddDirectory(Path.Combine(folderToZip, ddlFolderName));
    zip.Password = guid.ToString();
    zip.Save(zipFileName);
}
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName))
{
    zip.Password = guid.ToString();
    zip.ExtractAll(extractionPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```